# Generate ON / OFF flags in R data frame as value is encountered reading down rows within a group

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using dplyr to work with the following data frame within R.

```
dfInput <- data.frame(
  ItemID = c(1, 1, 1,1, 1, 2,2,2,2),
  RowID = c(1, 2 ,3, 4,5, 1, 2, 3, 4),
  VarCheck = c("X","Y","X","Z","X","X","Z","Y","Y")
)
```

At the start of each group I set a Flag to 0.  I would then like to read down the rows within each group and set a flag to 1 each time VarCheck has the value "Y".  This Flag is then retained at 1 for subsequent rows until VarCheck has the value "Z", at which point it is set to 0.

A result data frame is as follows:

```
 dfXX <- data.frame(
  ItemID = c(1, 1, 1,1, 1, 2,2,2,2),
  RowID = c(1, 2 ,3, 4,5, 1, 2, 3, 4),
  VarCheck = c("X","Y","X","Z","X","X","Z","Y","Y"),
  Flag = c(0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1)
)
```

How best to achieve this result? I have looked at using the lag function for Flag to carry the value forward, but until it is created for the first time, an error is thrown as the variable does not exist.  (In SAS the Retain function is used to ensure a value carries from one row to the next.)

Comment: No change - X is neutral and the preceding value is retained.  Essentially the rule is - if "Y", then set to 1, if "Z" set to 0, else retain the previous value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option

```
library(dplyr)
dfInput %>%
   group_by(ItemID, grp = cumsum(VarCheck %in% c("Y", "Z"))) %>% 
   mutate(Flag =  +("Y" %in% VarCheck)) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-grp)
# A tibble: 9 x 4
#  ItemID RowID VarCheck  Flag
#   <dbl> <dbl> <fct>    <int>
#1      1     1 X            0
#2      1     2 Y            1
#3      1     3 X            1
#4      1     4 Z            0
#5      1     5 X            0
#6      2     1 X            0
#7      2     2 Z            0
#8      2     3 Y            1
#9      2     4 Y            1
```